# Error in creation of a new Entity (FK constraint issue)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I'm having a bit of an... odd issue. I'm getting an error with saving a newly created entity that has a * to 1 relation with another entity. Bit difficult to explain but here's the set up:

(Note: I am using MVC 2 - Entity Framework 4)

My entities are set up as follows (names replaced for readability, but the structure is as described):
There are some managers in our company. (tblManagers) Each manager owns an undefined amount of Stores (tblStores). Each store has an undefined amount of Equipment (tblEquipment).
So my DataModel is as follows:

(tblManagers)  1<----->*  (tblStores)  1<------>*  (tblEquipment)

This setup is valid, as we already have a lot of data in there (from exporting an old Access file).

When creating a new equipment, you obviously have to select which store it belongs to. The value selected in the dropdownlist (the ID of the Store) is passed to the HttpPost method, which executes the following code:

*db is my database context variable*

```
myNewItem.tblStore = db.tblStores.Single(x => x.Id == store_id_from_dropdown);

db.tblEquipments.AddObject(myNewItem);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Which seems to me to be valid code. Resharper sees no issues, also no compile errors (or even warnings). However, when running the code, I encouter the following exception (thrown on db.SaveChanges()):

```
Entities in 'CMT_DevEntities.tbl_Stores' participate 
in the 'tblManagerstblStores' relationship. 
0 related 'tblManager' were found. 
1 'tblManager' is expected.
```

I have no idea why it's even looking at the tblManager as there is no reference to it in my code. I understand that this has to do with the relationship between managers and their stores, but I dont see *why*.

Here's the part that confuses me:

- When looking at the debugvalues of `myNewItem`, I can see the store is added to the entity. I can even check the tblManager property of the Store, and it is the correct tblManager. So this confirms everything is OK in the database (Stores couldn't even exist if they didn't have a Manager).
- I've actually left out a bit of the code. There is an exactly similar navigation property in the Equipment (let's say Supplier. The Supplier in turn has navigation property to a Country. The relations are exactly the same). I get no errors for this one though. Only the Store/Manager one.

I'm probably missing something, maybe something quite simple. Either way, I have no idea why this is happening.

So my question is: Given an entity created by the ModelBinder in MVC and an (int) ID for the navigation property, how do I add my new entity to the database?

Comment: _Not sure about EF, i think it's 4_ - then first find that out.

Comment: Confirmed it's 4. Updated post.

Comment: Does the `db.tblStores.Single(...)` and the `db.tblEquipments.AddObject(...)` really happen with the same instance of `db`?

Comment: The code is an exact copy paste. The function only has a using(var db = ....) block, and the snippet above is the content of the using() block.

Comment: What happens if you use `db.tblStores.Include("tblManager").Single(...)`? Does the error disappear then?

Comment: To be honest, I have no interest in testing that, as there are many more Navigation properties. My DataModel has 50-ish tables which are all interconnected, And Equipment is the 'lowest' layer of them all. From the Equipments you will always find a corresponding row in nearly each table (through 7-8 tiers of layers, Manager isn't the highest layer in the DataModel).

Comment: Sorry if that sounded blunt, not my intention. But it does seem an unnecessary hassle to have to include everyhting that might be connected. I tested it and still no luck, the same Exception is thrown.

Comment: I didn't propose this as solution. I agree that Include must not be necessary. Actually I expected that Include won't remove the exception (but I wasn't sure), but that means in my opinion that the problem is in the mapping of the relationship between store and manager and that means you probably must show more details. (The code above is correct and would work *if* the relationship is as expected, like in your other relationships.) Are your classes POCOs or `EntityObject`? DB-First or Model-First?

Comment: As I'm a self-taught programmer, I'm a bit fuzzy on definitions, sorry about that. I set up the DataModel in the .edmx file and then generated a database from the Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of loading all the `Store` entities, you can add a Foreign Key Id for `Store` to your `Equipment` entity (`equipment.StoreId`).

This will make sure that EF sees the relation between your newly created `Equipment` and your `Store` entity without loading the whole graph.

Since you are using the Model first approach, you can find the documentation on how to do this [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738477.aspx).

The important part is in the Note sections:

> You can choose to not add navigation properties or foreign key
>   properties to the entities at the ends of the association by clearing
>   the Navigation Property and Add foreign key properties to the  Entity checkboxes. If you add only one navigation property,
>   the association will be traversable in only one direction. If you add
>   no navigation properties, you must choose to add foreign key
>   properties in order to access entities at the ends of the association.
>   For many-to-many (*:*) and one-to-one (1:1) associations, you cannot
>   add foreign keys to the entities. For more information, see Defining
>   and Managing Relationships (Entity Framework).

You should check the 'Add foreign key properties to the 'Equipment' Entity' in the Add Association dialog. 
Using Foreign Key properties is a new feature in Entity Framework 4. It will make your live a lot easier.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2009/03/16/foreign-keys-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) you can find a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Hmmm I'm beginning to suspect this is some issue that has been hidden for a long time. I didn't build the program initially, and the guy before had a knack for experimenting with different types of coding and structures in general. Still not fully solved but you've helped me a long way, it'll get solved :) Thanks for the full explanation!

Comment: Feel free to ask more questions :) foreign keys are a nee concept in EF Older modes don't always have them It will defenitely improve your code if you add them

Comment: The annoying part is that the structure works. I've implemented many other pages and I can successfully use things like 'myEquimpentItem.Store.Name' and similar things. I can save the edits of existing equipment. I only encounter this issue when creating a new Equipment in the database.

Comment: Hah, I've found the issue after months of headbanging. Some snuck a HiddenFor(Store.ID) in my view, with a totally incorrect ID behind it. EF thought I was trying to add a new Store (as it was a nonexisting ID), which in turn caused the Store-Manager FK constraint to be violated. Flater: 1 ; Badly coded application: 186.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your entities properly:
if you have two entities linked throug foreign key then you need configure navigation property. Example:

```
public class Destination
{
    public int DestinationId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
    public List<Lodging> Lodgings { get; set; }
}

public class Lodging
{
     public int LodgingId { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public string Owner { get; set; }
     public bool IsResort { get; set; }
     public decimal MilesFromNearestAirport { get; set; }
     public int DestinationId { get; set; }
     public Destination Destination { get; set; }
}

internal class LodgingConfiguration:EntityTypeConfiguration<Charge>
{
    HasRequired(d=>d.Destination).WithMany(l=>l.Logings).HasForeignKey(d=>d.DestinationId)
}
```

Creating of Loging loks like:

```
var loging = new Loging
                 {
                     ...initialize properties...
                     Destination = new Destination{..initialize destination..}
                 }
context.Add(loging);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: He is using `ObjectContext` and Model-First, not `DbContext` and Code-First, so he can't use your proposal.

Comment: Slauma is correct. But still thanks for the explanation, I did learn something from your post :)

Comment: Yes, sorry for misunderstanding.